# Unable to edit .xhtml files on RAD 8.5/9.0

Tags: java, ibm-rad, ibm-was

It is showing the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.etools.references.internal.management.InternalReferenceManager.expandLinkText(InternalReferenceManager.java:473)
    at com.ibm.etools.references.management.ReferenceManager.expandLinkText(ReferenceManager.java:103)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.core.pdLinkFixupDelegates.LinkUtilBaseDelegate.getAbsURL(LinkUtilBaseDelegate.java:85)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.viewer.utils.LinkUtilBase.getAbsURL(LinkUtilBase.java:187)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.viewer.utils.LinkUtilBase.getAbsURL(LinkUtilBase.java:206)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.viewer.utils.LinkUtilBase.getAbsURL(LinkUtilBase.java:194)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editparts.adapter.SubModelAdapterFactory.getRawResFileName(SubModelAdapterFactory.java:101)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editparts.adapter.SubModelAdapter.getResFileName(SubModelAdapter.java:97)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editparts.adapter.SubModelAdapter.getModel(SubModelAdapter.java:52)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editparts.ElementEditPart.hasSubModel(ElementEditPart.java:1801)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.render.internal.style.extended.HTMLStyleJSPINCLUDE.getDisplayTypeFromElement(HTMLStyleJSPINCLUDE.java:45)
    at com.ibm.etools.xve.renderer.style.html.HTMLStyleImpl.getDisplayType(HTMLStyleImpl.java:258)
    at com.ibm.etools.xve.renderer.figures.ElementFigure.setStyle(ElementFigure.java:1956)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editparts.ElementEditPart.initStyle(ElementEditPart.java:745)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editparts.ElementEditPart.addNotify(ElementEditPart.java:758)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(AbstractEditPart.java:212)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editparts.NodeEditPart.refreshChildren(NodeEditPart.java:276)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editparts.ElementEditPart.refreshChildren(ElementEditPart.java:1531)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(AbstractEditPart.java:726)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(AbstractGraphicalEditPart.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(AbstractEditPart.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(AbstractGraphicalEditPart.java:223)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editparts.VisibleNodeEditPart.addNotify(VisibleNodeEditPart.java:216)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editparts.ElementEditPart.addNotify(ElementEditPart.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(AbstractEditPart.java:212)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editparts.NodeEditPart.refreshChildren(NodeEditPart.java:276)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editparts.ElementEditPart.refreshChildren(ElementEditPart.java:1531)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(AbstractEditPart.java:726)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(AbstractGraphicalEditPart.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(AbstractEditPart.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(AbstractGraphicalEditPart.java:223)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editparts.VisibleNodeEditPart.addNotify(VisibleNodeEditPart.java:216)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editparts.ElementEditPart.addNotify(ElementEditPart.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(AbstractEditPart.java:212)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editparts.NodeEditPart.refreshChildren(NodeEditPart.java:276)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editparts.ElementEditPart.refreshChildren(ElementEditPart.java:1531)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(AbstractEditPart.java:726)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(AbstractGraphicalEditPart.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(AbstractEditPart.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(AbstractGraphicalEditPart.java:223)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editparts.VisibleNodeEditPart.addNotify(VisibleNodeEditPart.java:216)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editparts.ElementEditPart.addNotify(ElementEditPart.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(AbstractEditPart.java:212)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editparts.NodeEditPart.refreshChildren(NodeEditPart.java:276)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editparts.ElementEditPart.refreshChildren(ElementEditPart.java:1531)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(AbstractEditPart.java:726)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(AbstractGraphicalEditPart.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(AbstractEditPart.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(AbstractGraphicalEditPart.java:223)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editparts.VisibleNodeEditPart.addNotify(VisibleNodeEditPart.java:216)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editparts.ElementEditPart.addNotify(ElementEditPart.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(AbstractEditPart.java:212)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editparts.NodeEditPart.refreshChildren(NodeEditPart.java:276)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editparts.ElementEditPart.refreshChildren(ElementEditPart.java:1531)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(AbstractEditPart.java:726)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(AbstractGraphicalEditPart.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(AbstractEditPart.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(AbstractGraphicalEditPart.java:223)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editparts.VisibleNodeEditPart.addNotify(VisibleNodeEditPart.java:216)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editparts.ElementEditPart.addNotify(ElementEditPart.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(AbstractEditPart.java:212)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editparts.NodeEditPart.refreshChildren(NodeEditPart.java:276)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editparts.OffRenderingEditPart.refreshChildren(OffRenderingEditPart.java:638)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(AbstractEditPart.java:726)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(AbstractGraphicalEditPart.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(AbstractEditPart.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(AbstractGraphicalEditPart.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(AbstractEditPart.java:212)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editparts.DocumentEditPart.refreshChildren(DocumentEditPart.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(AbstractEditPart.java:726)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(AbstractGraphicalEditPart.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(AbstractEditPart.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(AbstractGraphicalEditPart.java:223)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editparts.DocumentEditPart.addNotify(DocumentEditPart.java:739)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(AbstractEditPart.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.SimpleRootEditPart.setContents(SimpleRootEditPart.java:105)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editparts.HTMLGraphicalRootEditPart.setContents(HTMLGraphicalRootEditPart.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.AbstractEditPartViewer.setContents(AbstractEditPartViewer.java:617)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editparts.HTMLGraphicalViewerImpl.setContents(HTMLGraphicalViewerImpl.java:995)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editor.internal.page.design.WysiwygView.setModel(WysiwygView.java:881)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editor.internal.page.design.HTMLDesignPage.setModel(HTMLDesignPage.java:1567)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editor.HTMLEditor.createDesignPane(HTMLEditor.java:1559)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editor.HTMLEditor.access$21(HTMLEditor.java:1551)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editor.HTMLEditor$SplitPaneContainer.createPane(HTMLEditor.java:6149)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editor.internal.pane.PageDesignerPaneContainerForTwo.createAndAddPane(PageDesignerPaneContainerForTwo.java:355)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editor.internal.pane.PageDesignerPaneContainerForTwo.createPaneContainer(PageDesignerPaneContainerForTwo.java:78)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editor.HTMLEditor$SplitPaneContainer.createPaneContainer(HTMLEditor.java:6136)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editor.HTMLEditor$MyPaneManager.createTabs(HTMLEditor.java:6222)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editor.internal.pane.MultiPaneEditorPart.createPages(MultiPaneEditorPart.java:293)
    at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editor.HTMLEditor.createPages(HTMLEditor.java:1598)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPartControl(CompatibilityEditor.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:313)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:841)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:894)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:681)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$1.handleEvent(PartServiceImpl.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4687)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1029)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3047)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$22(WorkbenchPage.java:2969)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$8.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2951)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2947)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2911)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2902)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:655)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:614)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.handlers.OpenResourceHandler.execute(OpenResourceHandler.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.handlers.OpenResourceHandler.run(OpenResourceHandler.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.ActionDelegateHandlerProxy.execute(ActionDelegateHandlerProxy.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.executeCommand(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.press(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:496)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.processKeyEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.filterKeySequenceBindings(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.access$0(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:314)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher$KeyDownFilter.handleEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1262)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1052)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1104)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1100)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmChar(Widget.java:1521)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_CHAR(Control.java:4640)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.WM_CHAR(Tree.java:5981)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4528)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.windowProc(Tree.java:5977)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4976)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2546)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3756)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Comment: @Berger Not a duplicate.  OP can't fix this NullPointerException since it is an error in RAD, not their own code.

Comment: This is probably a product issue, so you should probably open a PMR with IBM.

Comment: @Brett Kail :  Oh yes sorry, I missed that point .